# Multiple assignments to function return value

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

In a SystemVerilog function, is it legal to do multiple assignments to the implicitly-declared return variable? See the following function for an example:

```
  localparam int Q=1,I=0;
  function logic [1:0][Q:I][15:0] Cast24to16(input logic [1:0][Q:I][23:0] din);
    foreach (Cast24to16[n,iq])
      Cast24to16[n][iq] = din[n][iq][23 -: 8];
  endfunction
```

The language reference manual, IEEE Std 1800-2017, sec 13.4.1 states:

> Function return values can be specified in two ways, either by using a return statement or by assigning a value to the internal variable with the same name as the function.

This seems a little unclear as to whether you can assign multiple times, like in my example. Furthermore, the example from the LRM directly after this statement and also all other examples I can find online all show the implicit return value only being assigned once. This makes me feel a bit unsettled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LRM also says just before the section you quoted

> The function definition shall implicitly declare a variable, internal to the function, with the same name as the function.

I think you can safely assume that if there is no explicit `return` statement, it effectively inserts an implicit `return (var_function_name);`

Also, if you declare your function with a static lifetime (which is the implicit default lifetime in a module), that implicit return variable has a static lifetime as well. That means it retains its value from the last time you called the function regardless of whether you assign it or not.

```
module top;
  
  function int countme;
    countme++;
  endfunction
  
  initial repeat (10) $display(countme());
endmodule
```